# Dropwizard - how to achieve custom authorization scheme?

Tags: rest, authentication, webserver, authorization, dropwizard

I am trying to use Dropwizard as a full web server, combining serving public pages, protected pages and data through REST API. So, I am validating the ability to protect some routes by applying a custom authorization scheme based on a computed token and a realm to manage different security areas.

I have difficulties to understand how to achieve the purpose. The sequence I was expecting is the following :

- display an HTML login page with a user form
- user enters its credentials
- call an authenticate route to validate credentials and create a token for the user. Send back a welcome page with an Authorization header like : MyScheme token="TYGDF655HD88D098D0970CUCHD987D897", realm="SUPER SECRET STUFF"
- user click a link to list its invoice : /html/invoices
- this route is protected by DropWizard @Auth annotation
- no header is sent by the browser so the server answer with a 401 response with a header : WWW-Authenticate MyScheme realm="SUPER SECRET STUFF", challenging the browser to give it an authorization header matching the challenge

Unfortunatly, the browser didn't send it this header. According to many articles, I thought browser managed authorization cache for all received credentials, their scheme and parameters (such as realm).

It seems browser have this behavior for well known schemes such as Basic authentication, but not for custom scheme (by the way, it's usually an issue for basic auth since browser can't "logout" a user since he does not erase the web history or close the browser).

How do you think it's possible to tell a browser to cache authorization credentials and to add them each time a server request is challenging it with the right scheme / realm ?

I could display here all the example codes I use to make this example run.

A reference (good to read) : RFC1945 at https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1945#section-11

Thank you for your help.

Running dropWizard 0.9.2 on Jdk Oracle 1.8 / Debian 8.

Answer (score 0):

Browser doesn't manage authorization. It never does, or at least never should.

Server should always keep its cache, and verify input from the browser.

At a basic level, all of the fields you need, are part of the HTTP Header. If you inject the request, you'll have access to them.

If dropwizard doesn't have things you need, you can always ignore everything, and simply read the request headers and do the custom processing you need.

For instance, add a Filter which sets the `realm`, something like `WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="myrealm:"`

`Authorization: MyScheme Ceasar-cipher-password`. You'll need to parse it and process it yourself, perhaps set up an incoming Filter on all requests, or selective requests.

Is it a good idea, I'll let you be the judge. Perhaps, in your use case it makes sense.

If you have a look at the source code and how the BasicCredentials are used, perhaps, it can provide insight in a potential solution you may adapt yourself.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. If browser shouldn't manage _Authorization cache_, how could he reply to a **401 query**, which challenge it about some credentials in a security area ?   If basic auth is involved, browser could open a login dialog then send back appropriate header, but for unknown scheme, how to proceed ?

Comment: @mnementh64 Browser's job is to simply construct a request and pass it on to the server. Server responds with an error message. So if you are getting 401, server is processing it. You should debug the server code in my opinion. You should write code at the server which will process the custom header.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I have not made myself clear. That is the server that answer a response with a 401 status, and that is normal because the resource you want to get access needs authentication. So it is up to the browser to do something with that. I know this case is usually managed through cookies (that are re-sent by browser in every request). There must be something i miss ...

Comment: @mnementh64 Once the serve returns a 401, you need to manage in your application what you need to do.... Some frameworks might do it automatically, others, you might need to write some code for ... perhaps, you can clarify where the problem is ..